# How to set the ToolTip in only one control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have use the ToolTip with Behavior. So, when click on the control, ToolTip will be appear.

However, when change the disabled of control, this ToolTip is not appeared.
Because, mouse events were not activated. So, i was used the ContentContorl and it can be activate the mouse event when change the disabled.

But, when i have several control in one Grid, i dont know that how to activate the only one control.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl" >
        <Setter Property="localToolTip:ToolTipTouchScreenBehavior.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Setter Property="localToolTip:ToolTipTouchScreenBehavior.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
    </Style>        
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl ToolTip="This is ToolTip5 Test.">
            <Grid IsEnabled="False">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ToolTip Test5"  FontSize="25" 
                            ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Width="200" />

            </Grid>
</ContentControl>


public class ToolTipTouchScreenBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{

    public static DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool),
            typeof(ToolTipTouchScreenBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsEnabledChanged));

    public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject uie)
    {
        return (bool)uie.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject uie, bool value)
    {
        uie.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject dpo, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        UIElement uie = dpo as UIElement;

        if (uie != null)
        {

            var behColl = Interaction.GetBehaviors(uie);

            var existingBehavior = behColl.FirstOrDefault(b => b.GetType() ==
                  typeof(ToolTipTouchScreenBehavior)) as ToolTipTouchScreenBehavior;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue == false && existingBehavior != null)
                behColl.Remove(existingBehavior);
            else if ((bool)e.NewValue == true && existingBehavior == null)
                behColl.Add(new ToolTipTouchScreenBehavior());

        }

    }

    Timer timer { get; set; }
    ToolTip toolTip { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        toolTip = new ToolTip();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;

        AssociatedObject.MouseLeave += OnMouseLeave;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += OnMouseLeftButtonUp;

    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.MouseLeave -= OnMouseLeave;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp -= OnMouseLeftButtonUp;
    }

    public void OnMouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseToolTip();
    }

    public void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {



            //var temp = AssociatedObject.ToolTip;
            //if (((dynamic)sender).ToolTip != null)
            if (AssociatedObject.ToolTip != null)
            {
                if (AssociatedObject.ToolTip is string)
                    toolTip.Content = AssociatedObject.ToolTip;
                else
                    toolTip = (ToolTip)AssociatedObject.ToolTip;

                //Debug.WriteLine("ToolTip Opened: {0}, ToolTip Value: {1}", toolTip.IsOpen, toolTip.ToolTip);

                toolTip.IsOpen = true;
                timer.Start();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }



    }

    private void CloseToolTip()
    {

        if (timer.Enabled)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }

        if (toolTip != null)
        {
            toolTip.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)CloseToolTip, DispatcherPriority.Send);
    }

}
```

When i have above code, i just want to add the ToolTip for only TextBlock. not TextBox.

How to apply the ToolTip to only one special control?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should be asking how to react to a mouse event on a disabled control in order to activate the tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to react to mouse interaction for an disabled element, you can add a visual to the adorner layer (which will stay enabled for a disabled underlying element) and capture input there. The following is just a rough sketch with an Adorner that executes an arbitrary action on `MouseLeftButtonUp` only for disabled controls and an attached property to connect the adorner to some framework element (you may want to utilize your behavior instead).

```
public class DisabledMouseUpAdorner : Adorner
{
    private Border _Child;
    private Action _OnDisabledMouseUp;

    public DisabledMouseUpAdorner(FrameworkElement element, Action onDisabledMouseUp)
        : base(element)
    {
        _OnDisabledMouseUp = onDisabledMouseUp;
        _Child = new Border();
        _Child.MouseLeftButtonUp += Adorner_Click;
        // actually you probably want an invisible adorner, but for demonstration lets add some color
        //_Child.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        _Child.Background = new SolidColorBrush(new Color() { A = 20, R = 255, G = 0, B = 0 });
        _Child.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        _Child.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        _Child.IsHitTestVisible = !element.IsEnabled;
        element.IsEnabledChanged += Adorned_IsEnabledChanged;
        AddVisualChild(_Child);
    }


    void Adorned_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Child.IsHitTestVisible = !AdornedElement.IsEnabled;
    }


    void Adorner_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_OnDisabledMouseUp != null)
        {
            _OnDisabledMouseUp();
        }
    }


    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    { get { return 1; } }


    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index != 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return _Child;
    }


    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        _Child.Measure(constraint);
        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }


    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        _Child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), finalSize));
        return finalSize;
    }
}



public static class Attached
{
    public static bool GetToolTipOnClickEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ToolTipOnClickEnabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetToolTipOnClickEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ToolTipOnClickEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ToolTipOnClickEnabled.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipOnClickEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ToolTipOnClickEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(Attached), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnToolTipOnClickChanged)));

    private static void OnToolTipOnClickChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = d as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null)
        {
            if (element.IsLoaded)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
                {
                    AddOverlay(element);
                }
                else
                {
                    RemoveOverlay(element);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                element.Loaded -= Element_Loaded;
                element.Loaded += Element_Loaded;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Element_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var elem = sender as FrameworkElement;
        elem.Loaded -= Element_Loaded;
        if (GetToolTipOnClickEnabled(elem))
        {
            AddOverlay(elem);
        }
        else
        {
            RemoveOverlay(elem);
        }
    }

    private static void RemoveOverlay(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        var adl = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(element);
        var ad = adl.GetAdorners(element);
        foreach (var item in ad)
        {
            if (item is DisabledMouseUpAdorner) adl.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    private static void AddOverlay(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        var a = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(element);
        if (a != null)
        {
            a.Add(new DisabledMouseUpAdorner(element, () => ClickHandler(element)));
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    // whatever you actually want to do when the adorner triggers
    private static void ClickHandler(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        if (element.ToolTip == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var tt = element.ToolTip as ToolTip ?? new ToolTip() { Content = element.ToolTip, StaysOpen = false };
        tt.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
<TextBlock Text="ToolTip Test5"  FontSize="25"
    ToolTip="Shows on click when disabled"
    local:Attached.ToolTipOnClickEnabled="True" />
```

Comment: Wow!!, it is working and very helpful to me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Song if it is that helpful you should probably mark it as the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is same as mentioned by **grek40** then the following is the answer:

If you do want the tooltip to be displayed when the parent control is disabled, you can set the ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled property to true.
[WPF 2000things](https://wpf.2000things.com/?s=tooltip)

Comment: I think the point in question is to show the tooltip not just automatically on mouse over, but to handle special input devices (touchpad) where the mouse wont magically stay over some control. Still its good to mention this property for most normal use cases.